# categorical predictors in a GLM

Tags: r, regression, self-study, logistic

I need some help answering a homework question,

[Question](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xs1gflfl063m4lo/IMG_20141201_123018~2.jpg?dl=0)

I have entered the data into R using assignments

```
data <- data.frame(category=c(1:8),
                   obese =c(597,380,665,524,1014,365,942,552),
                   number = c(2346,1659,2576,1732,1499,639,1491,769), 
                   male=c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0),
                   white =c(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0),
                   younger =c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0))
```

I then used

```
output = glm(obese ~ male + white + younger, family = binomial)
```

to model the data. But this doesn't seem to be working. I've not really used much R before for GLMs or logistic regression and I don't understand how to get GLM from categorial, binary predictor variables.
If someone could explain the theory behind because searching online I have only found answers where the response variable is binary and this seems straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Your data already seems to be summarized: in the 1st category (younger white males), 597 out of 2346 subjects are obese. At least, that's my understanding - it's always good to *really* understand the data you are modeling.

If my interpretation is right, then an easy way to do this seems to be to turn your first row into 597 rows with `obese`=1 and 2346-597 rows with `obese`=0, then your GLM should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your GLM statement will only work if the data are lined up one line per case. In your homework, the cases are aggregated, so the R code needs to be changed somewhat:

```
nonObese <- number - obese
glm(cbind(obese, nonObese)) ~ male + white + younger, family = binomial)
```

See [here](http://data.princeton.edu/R/glms.html) for a more in-depth tutorial.